# Preg Match Word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this string.

```
$string = 'product_posting_list_name_1';
```

I am using this to find the match but it is not finding the match. Can anyone explain to me why? I want to match up to the last underscore and the number.

```
preg_match('/\bproduct_posting_list_name\b/', $string)
```

Comment: We assume your string is quoted...

Comment: yes you are correct. I made the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_` the underscore, [is considered to be a word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), which is *inside* the boundaries you have placed via `\b`, not a boundary itself.  Your regular expression is looking for complete words between boundaries, but the boundary occurs after the `_1`.

To match it, you cannot use a boundary on the right side.

```
$string = "product_posting_list_name_1";
// Replace the right-side \b with a [\d]+ to indicate 1 or more digits, followed by the \b boundary.
preg_match('/\bproduct_posting_list_name_[\d]+\b/', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. Do you have any suggestions as to where there might be a Regex 101?

Comment: The link inside my answer to www.regular-expressions.info is the best place I've ever found

Answer (score 0):

not regex, but works:

```
$string = 'product_posting_list_name_1';
if (strpos($string, 'product_posting_list_name') === 0) { echo 'found'; }
```